# GAS: Replacing every regex-match in all sheets with cell address

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to search for all instances of 'xyz' in a Google spreadsheet and replace every 'y' with the cell reference and sheet name.

Imagine I have this table in a sheet called 'Monday':

```
A      B
1 xyz
2      xyz
```

I then want the text in A1 and B2 to be replaced so the result is this:

```
A            B
1 xA1Mondayz
2            xB2Mondayz
```

And so on for the remaining sheets.

So far I've not found a similar question...

My code looks something like this:

```
function replaceY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  //Do for each sheet
  for(m = 0; m < sheets.length; m++){
    var data = sheets[m].getDataRange().getValues();
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      for(var n = 0; n < data[0].length; n++){
        if(typeof(data[i][n]) == 'string'){
          var regex = /.*(y).*/ig;
          var result = regex.exec(data[i][n]);
          if(result[1] !== null){ 
            var currentCellAddress = sheets[m].getActiveRange();
            // Loop through regex matches and replace every group
            // with currentCellAddress and sheet name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I realize I might be out of my depth here, but if you know of a solution, I'll be glad to see it!

*update*
The error I'm receiving is: Cannot read property '1' of null. 
And that's without any looping through matches.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Are you getting an error? :)

Comment: @sniperd Yes. TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null.
And that's without any looping through matches.

Comment: why you don't use indexOf('String') method?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good. The following additions worked for me:

```
function replaceY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();      // Declaring variables  
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();              // outside of the loop.
  var regex = /y/ig;     // Using a simpler regex.
  var data, name, str, range, result, startRow, startCol, row, col, notation, replaceWith; 

  //Do for each sheet
  for(m = 0; m < sheets.length; m++){
    range = sheets[m].getDataRange()
    data = range.getValues();

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      for(var n = 0; n < data[0].length; n++){

        if(typeof(data[i][n]) == 'string'){
          result = regex.exec(data[i][n]);

          if(result !== null){ // * I removed the [1] because result was not considered
                               // * an array for some reason.
            name = sheets[m].getName();

            // get the A1 notation, then combine with the sheet name.
            // create a range with current indices, then get its notation.
            notation = sheets[m].getRange(i+1, n+1).getA1Notation();
            replaceWith = notation+name;
            data[i][n] = data[i][n].replace(regex, replaceWith);

          }
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
  }
}
```

It seems removing the `[1]` in your code (`result[1]`) also prevented the error you were receiving.

Please let me know if it works for you too!